# <h:selectManyCheckbox> binding solution

Tags: java, jsf, backing-beans

i have one component as below,which is binded by HtmlSelectManyCheckbox,

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="chk_weekdays"
    onclick="restrictCheck(this)"
    binding="#{Holiday_Declaration.chk_weekedays}"
    >
           <f:selectItem id="chk_1" itemLabel="Monday"  itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem id="chk_2" itemLabel="Tuesday"  itemValue="2" />
            <f:selectItem id="chk_3" itemLabel="Wednesday"  itemValue="3" />
            <f:selectItem id="chk_4" itemLabel="Thursday"  itemValue="4" />
             <f:selectItem id="chk_5" itemLabel="Friday"  itemValue="5" />
             <f:selectItem id="chk_6" itemLabel="Saturday"  itemValue="6" />
             <f:selectItem id="chk_0" itemLabel="Sunday"  itemValue="0" /></h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

and i want total number of checked checkboxes and their values using backing bean Holiday_Declaration.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1):

Have following field in your managed bean

```
 private List<String> chk_weekedays;
 // getters/setters
```

Cover your component in an `h:form` and on submit access this list from some action

Comment: and replace `binding` by `value`.

Comment: in backing bean i have,  private HtmlSelectManyCheckbox chk_weekedays = new HtmlSelectManyCheckbox();

Comment: @Annu change it to `binding="#{Holiday_Declaration.chk_weekedays}"`  `value="#{Holiday_Declaration.chk_weekedays}"`

Comment: @Annu You don't need that I guess :)